# spark- group all elements of array column into batches using scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with a column of array type where the number of elements differs between rows as seen in GPS_Array_Size of the below Input Dataframe.

I need to post an http request to an external service with 5000 elements at a time by also embedding the "requestid" field into each tuple as shown in the Output Dataframe.

**Input Dataframe schema:-**

```
root
 |-- requestid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- GPS_Array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- GPSLatitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- GPSLongitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- GPS_Array_Size: long (nullable = true)
```

**Input DataFrame:-**

| requestid | GPS_Array | GPS_Array_Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | [{"timestamp":a1,"GPSLatitude":a1,"GPSLongitude":a1},{"timestamp":a2,"GPSLatitude":a2,"GPSLongitude":a2},...{"timestamp":a6431,"GPSLatitude":a6431,"GPSLongitude":a6431}] | 6431 |
| bbb | [{"timestamp":b1,"GPSLatitude":b1,"GPSLongitude":b1},{"timestamp":b2,"GPSLatitude":b2,"GPSLongitude":b2},...{"timestamp":b11876,"GPSLatitude":b11876,"GPSLongitude":b11876}] | 11876 |
| ccc | [{"timestamp":c1,"GPSLatitude":c1,"GPSLongitude":c1},{"timestamp":c2,"GPSLatitude":c2,"GPSLongitude":c2},...{"timestamp":c763,"GPSLatitude":c763,"GPSLongitude":c763}] | 763 |
| ddd | [{"timestamp":d1,"GPSLatitude":d1,"GPSLongitude":d1},{"timestamp":d2,"GPSLatitude":d2,"GPSLongitude":d2},...{"timestamp":d5187,"GPSLatitude":d5187,"GPSLongitude":d5187}] | 5187 |
| eee | [{"timestamp":e1,"GPSLatitude":e1,"GPSLongitude":e1},{"timestamp":e2,"GPSLatitude":e2,"GPSLongitude":e2},...{"timestamp":e1023,"GPSLatitude":e1023,"GPSLongitude":e1023}] | 1023 |

**Output Dataframe schema:-**

```
root
 |-- New_GPS_Array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- requestid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- GPSLatitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- GPSLongitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- New_GPS_Array_Size: long (nullable = true)
```

**Output DataFrame:-**

| New_GPS_Array | New_GPS_Array_Size |
| --- | --- |
| [{"requestid":"aaa_1","timestamp":a1,"GPSLatitude":a1,"GPSLongitude":a1},{"requestid":"aaa_1","timestamp":a2,"GPSLatitude":a2,"GPSLongitude":a2},...{"requestid":"aaa_1","timestamp":a5000,"GPSLatitude":a5000,"GPSLongitude":a5000}] | 5000 |
| [{"requestid":"aaa_2","timestamp":a5001,"GPSLatitude":a5001,"GPSLongitude":a5001},{"requestid":"aaa_2","timestamp":a5002,"GPSLatitude":a5002,"GPSLongitude":a5002},...{"requestid":"aaa_2","timestamp":a6431,"GPSLatitude":a6431,"GPSLongitude":a6431},{"requestid":"bbb_1","timestamp":b1,"GPSLatitude":b1,"GPSLongitude":b1},...{"requestid":"bbb_1","timestamp":b3569,"GPSLatitude":b3569,"GPSLongitude":b3569} ] | 5000 |
| [{"requestid":"bbb_2","timestamp":b3570,"GPSLatitude":b3570,"GPSLongitude":b3570},{"requestid":"bbb_2","timestamp":b3571,"GPSLatitude":b3571,"GPSLongitude":b3571},...{"requestid":"bbb_2","timestamp":b8569,"GPSLatitude":b8569,"GPSLongitude":b8569} ] | 5000 |
| [{"requestid":"bbb_3","timestamp":b8570,"GPSLatitude":b8570,"GPSLongitude":b8570},{"requestid":"bbb_3","timestamp":b8571,"GPSLatitude":b8571,"GPSLongitude":b8571},...{"requestid":"bbb_3","timestamp":b11876,"GPSLatitude":b11876,"GPSLongitude":b11876},{"requestid":"ccc_1","timestamp":c1,"GPSLatitude":c1,"GPSLongitude":c1},...{"requestid":"ccc_1","timestamp":c763,"GPSLatitude":c763,"GPSLongitude":c763},{"requestid":"ddd_1","timestamp":d1,"GPSLatitude":d1,"GPSLongitude":d1},...{"requestid":"ddd_1","timestamp":d930,"GPSLatitude":d930,"GPSLongitude":d930} ] | 5000 |
| [{"requestid":"ddd_2","timestamp":d931,"GPSLatitude":d931,"GPSLongitude":d931},{"requestid":"ddd_2","timestamp":d932,"GPSLatitude":d932,"GPSLongitude":d932},...{"requestid":"ddd_2","timestamp":d5187,"GPSLatitude":d5187,"GPSLongitude":d5187},{"requestid":"eee_1","timestamp":e1,"GPSLatitude":e1,"GPSLongitude":e1},...{"requestid":"eee_1","timestamp":e743,"GPSLatitude":e743,"GPSLongitude":e743} ] | 5000 |
| [{"requestid":"eee_2","timestamp":e744,"GPSLatitude":e744,"GPSLongitude":e744},{"requestid":"eee_2","timestamp":e745,"GPSLatitude":e745,"GPSLongitude":e745},...{"requestid":"eee_2","timestamp":e1023,"GPSLatitude":e1023,"GPSLongitude":e1023}] | 280 |

As shown requestid needs to change for every new batch.

My Solution was to use the explode function to create a row for every element in the GPS_Array and then assign an index based on row number. So if I have 700 million rows after exploding then 1 to 700,000,000. The index is divided by 5000 to get the quotient and then the quotients are grouped.

​Row numbers 0 to 4999 will have quotient 0, row numbers 5000 to 9999 will have quotient 1 and row numbers 10000 to 14999 will have quotient 2 ..etc

explodedDF.withColumn("index", row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id()))).withColumn("id", floor($"id" / 5000).groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"GPS_Array"))

I believe the part that does the indexing brings all the records to 1 spark worker node since it has to auto increment over each record.

Can batching into 5000 elements per request be done more efficiently?

Version : (spark 2.45 and scala 2.11)

Comment: have you tried using `repartition` and `spark_partition_id` as we discussed last time?

Comment: Yes. But to group 700 million records into 140,000 batches of 5000 I would require to repartition the dataframe by 140,000 and then assign `spark_partition_id` `explodedDF.repartition(140000).withColumn("id", spark_partition_id())`